# Attentive Attention Mechanism for Answer Representation - Keras Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, attention-model

With reference to the paper "A Stacked BiLSTM Neural Network Based on Coattention Mechanism for Question Answering" (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cin/2019/9543490/), I am trying to write a custom keras layer to implement the below set of equations.

My context vector shapes for question and answer are as below.

Shape of Context vector of Question (CQ):  (512, 256)

Shape of Context vector of Answer   (CA):  (512, 256)

**Expected output:** Cosine score given the above two context vectors as inputs.

[image]

[image]

This is my code for the same.

```
class score(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units):
        super(score, self).__init__()
        # Initializing the weights
        self.Wam = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units) # Attention matrix of CA at time t.
        self.Wqm = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units) # Attention matrix of OQ
        self.Wms = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units) # Attention weight vector

    def call (self, CQ, CA):

        OQ = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(CQ)
        print(OQ.shape)
        CA = tf.expand_dims(CA,1)
        #Maq = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(self.Wam, CA) + tf.matmul(self.Wqm, OQ))
        Maq = tf.nn.tanh(self.Wam(CA) + self.Wqm(OQ))
        Saq  = tf.exp(tf.linalg.matmul(Wms, Maq, transpose_a = True, transpose_b = False))
        OA = CA * Saq
        OA = tf.reduce_sum(OA, axis = 1)

        # Calcutate Cosine similarity of vectors OQ and OA
        dot_product = tf.tensordot(OQ, OA, axes=0)
        # Normalize input
        norm_OQ = tf.nn.l2_normalize(OQ)
        norm_OA = tf.nn.l2_normalize(OA)
        scoreCosine = dot_product / (norm_OQ * norm_OA)

        #Normalize the cosine similarity to the [0, 1] interval 
        scoreCosine = 0.5 * (scoreCosine) + 0.5

        return scoreCosine

score_layer = score(10)
scoreCosine = score_layer(CQ, CA)
```

I am facing issues with matrix shapes in each step. I tried to break the steps and execute each separately.

**Issues I am facing:**

1) Input matrices are of shape 2D but GlobalMaxPool1D layer (1st equation) expects 3D input and produces 2D output.

2) I initialized attention matrices (Wam, Wqm) and attention weight vector (Wms) as dense layer with 10 units (Reference Bahdanau Attention layer here -> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention). Is it correct? This is not working for equation 3 (Wms transpose) as it is not a Tensor but a dense layer.

Please advise if this was correct approach or where am I doing incorrect. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.